# SQL query for checking if rows are in incorrect order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with this structure:

| Id | Foo |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 13 |
| 3 | 14 |
| 4 | 15 |
| 5 | 16 |

Note that both tables are in an ascending order. However, due to reasons some values in column `Foo` are not in the correct order:

| Id | Foo |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 13 |
| 3 | 15 |
| 4 | 14 |
| 5 | 16 |

Note that the `Foo` column is now no longer correctly ordered: `Foo` 14 and 15 are switched. I need a query that returns the `ID` 3 or 4, so that I know which rows are not correctly ordered and can manually inspect them. There are no gaps in the number series of either column.

Comment: Are the values of `Foo` actually equal to `Id` like in your example? Are the values of both columns sequential like in your example or can there be gaps?

Comment: Hi Stu, no, `Foo` and `Id` are not equal. They're both different series of integers. Neither have gaps. I'll update the question accordingly

Comment: Is it only two rows that are "swapped" or could it be a sequence where you want to find more than 1 row

Comment: There could be multiple swapped rows. Thanks for your time so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you describe a simple *exists* correlation should give your desired result:

```
select Id
from t
where exists (
  select * from t t2
  where t2.id = t.id + 1 and t2.foo < t.Foo
);
```

Example [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ef1e8c9a85ffe19d190a58060bc43f3d)

Comment: Works great, thanks! What's not great is that I'm getting a lot of results from this query which means I got a lot of work to do now...

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using `LEAD` or `LAG`

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      nextFoo = LEAD(t.Foo) OVER (ORDER BY t.ID)
    FROM t
) t
WHERE t.Foo > t.nextFoo;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=de597429540629c96d01996787401814)